# Meaning of 'manipulate'

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Those politicians cunningly **manipulate** the populist sentiment among people.*

In the above sentence what is the exact meaning of 'manipulate' between below two?

1. take advantage of
2. generate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sense here is “control”, like how a puppeteer controls a puppet by *manipulating* the strings.